# for-loop:The entries in vector A are to be replaced by the entries in vector B

Tags: r, for-loop

I reduced the problem to a small example. I hope it is helpful and understandable.

Given are the two vectors A and B. The entries in vector A are to be replaced by the entries in vector B. The replacement should be done with the absolute minimum difference of the entries. After replacing all entries in vector A, the new vector should be saved.
Maybe a for loop is a good idea?(also for large vectors?)
Thank you very much for your help!

For example:

```
A <- c(1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5) 

B <- c(1.25, 1.45)
```

**for-loop should work like this:**

> 1.2 - **1.25** = **0.05**
>
> 1.2 - 1.45 = 0.25

etc.

`0.05` is the absolute minimum, replacing `1.2` with `1.25`

The new vector should look like this:

```
newVector <- c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.45, 1.45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea using `outer` and `max.col`

```
B[max.col(-abs(outer(A, B, `-`)))]
# [1] 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.45 1.45
```

Should be fine to use if `A` and `B` are not too large.

**step by step**

`outer(A, B, "-")` returns the following matrix

```
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] -0.05 -0.25
#[2,]  0.05 -0.15
#[3,]  0.05 -0.15
#[4,]  0.15 -0.05
#[5,]  0.25  0.05
```

where the first column is the result of `A - B[1]` and the second column is `A - B[2]`. For each row we need to find the column position of the absolute minimum.

There is no `min.col` function therefore the minus in

```
max.col(-abs(outer(A, B, `-`)))
```

which returns

```
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

We finally use this vector to extract the desired values from `B`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

With `sapply` this can be easily done without a `for`-loop:

```
newVector <- sapply(A,function(x) B[which.min(abs(x-B))])
```

Comment: Just for completeness, of course we are not avoiding a `for` loop in general, but we are using a `for` loop on the  `C` level which is supposed to be much faster than an `R` `for` loop: [GitHub](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/178cff8daa661084da0e157f418b84f570604091/src/main/apply.c#L67)

Comment: Yes if course you're right about that thotal, somewhere there needs to be a `for` loop. But additionally to the (nowadays often only slight) improvement in speed, the use of the `apply` family forces you to adhere to the `R`-paradigmas, which I think is especially good for people who are learning the language

Answer (score 0):

First get the index of the minimum of the difference of all elements of  `A` with  `B`:

```
(ind <- sapply(A, function(a) which.min(abs(B - a))))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2
```

Then replace the values by the respective values in `B`:

```
B[ind]
# [1] 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.45 1.45
```

This form for illustrative purposes. Short code would be directly like this:

```
sapply(A, function(a) B[which.min(abs(B - a))])
# [1] 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.45 1.45
```